# Div auto-placement based on popularity

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a css grid with autoplacement that places the div based on the popularity (number of clicks) the specific div has.

This probably needs some jquery or js to achieve this. And I was wondering how or if there is something already available that I can look in too.

I already know how the css works. So I can make the div in a css grid with child names per div.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store the amount of clicks and then use javascript to place the div in the correct order depending on how much clicks they have.

Comment: Store it with mysql?

Comment: You can store it in MySQL, plain text file or json